# Deep Learning with multiple Input-Models

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm, text-classification

I am trying to make a model where I first can do a text-clasification with an LSTM layer and for the dense layer after that I want to add some more data. I tried to do that the same way it is described here: https://medium.com/@armandj.olivares/a-basic-nlp-tutorial-for-news-multiclass-categorization-82afa6d46aa5

That is how my code looks like:

```
embedding_dim = 300
inp_dim = X_train.shape[1]
text_data = Input(shape=(max_length,), name="X_train")
meta_data = Input(shape=(17,), name="X_train_meta")

x1 = (Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embedding_dim, input_length=max_length))(X_train)
x2 = (LSTM(300, dropout = 0.2, recurrent_dropout = 0.2, return_sequences=True))(x1)
x3 = concatenate([x2, X_train_meta], axis = 1)
x4 = (Dense(300, activationon = "relu"))(x3)
x5 = Dropout(0.2)(x4)
x6 = (Dense(300, activationon = "relu"))(x5)
x7 = BatchNormalization()(x6)
x8 = (Dense(4, activation='softmax'))(x6)

model = Model(inputs = [X_train, X_train_meta], outputs = x8)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit([X_train, X_train_meta], y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=500, 
          validation_data=[X_test, y_test], class_weight=class_weight)

print(model.summary)
```

The dimensions:

```
print(vocab_size)
print(inp_dim)
print(embedding_dim)
print(max_length)

78002
2395
300
2395
```

with this code I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\.conda\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
    309             try:
--> 310                 K.is_keras_tensor(x)
    311             except ValueError:

~\.conda\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in is_keras_tensor(x)
    696         raise ValueError('Unexpectedly found an instance of type `' +
--> 697                          str(type(x)) + '`. '
    698                          'Expected a symbolic tensor instance.')

ValueError: Unexpectedly found an instance of type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-e5a200494ddc> in <module>
      6 #x1 = (Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embedding_dim, input_length=max_length))(X_train)
      7 
----> 8 x1 = (Embedding(input_dim=inp_dim, output_dim=embedding_dim, input_length=max_length))(X_train)
      9 
     10 x2 = (LSTM(300, dropout = 0.2, recurrent_dropout = 0.2, return_sequences=True))(x1)

~\.conda\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in symbolic_fn_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     73         if _SYMBOLIC_SCOPE.value:
     74             with get_graph().as_default():
---> 75                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     76         else:
     77             return func(*args, **kwargs)

~\.conda\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    444                 # Raise exceptions in case the input is not compatible
    445                 # with the input_spec specified in the layer constructor.
--> 446                 self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
    447 
    448                 # Collect input shapes to build layer.

~\.conda\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
    314                                  'Received type: ' +
    315                                  str(type(x)) + '. Full input: ' +
--> 316                                  str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the layer '
    317                                  'should be tensors.')
    318 

ValueError: Layer embedding_7 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. Full input: [array([[  372,  1977,  2605, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [10255,    47, 10256, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [ 6455,     5, 20178, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       ...,
       [ 3032,   267,     5, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [ 8691,     5, 77969, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [42160, 12782,     5, ...,     0,     0,     0]])]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

So there something is wrong with my Embedding layer, but I don't know where I made the error. Can someone help me?

I have one additional question: How to start the training of the model? Is the code with `model.fit(...)` correct?

Thank you!
Daniel

Comment: You created two Input layers but you are not using them, you need to use them to provide inputs to the model, not pass the training set directly to the layers.

Comment: Ok, so I changed `x1 = (Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embedding_dim, input_length=max_length))(X_train)` to `x1 = (Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embedding_dim, input_length=max_length))(text_data )` and `x3 = concatenate([x2, X_train_meta], axis = 1)` to `x3 = concatenate([x2, meta_data], axis = 1)`. Then there is no error at the embedding layer, but I got a new error: `ValueError: A Concatenate layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 2395, 300), (None, 17)]`